# SELICHOT Request for Forgiveness

Tags: discussion

**My apologies for posting this under Questions, I could find no other appropriate place**

B"H
I feel that I would like to ask forgiveness from the Moderators, and the many other persons here,especially @Heshy, who took the trouble to react to my questions.

Selichot (Hebrew: סליחות) means 'sorry/forgiveness prayers'.

This is the season to begin the process of asking forgiveness for wrongs done to other people.
According to Jewish tradition, God cannot forgive us for sins committed against another person until we have first obtained forgiveness from the person we have wronged.. 
In the Jewish tradition, the whole of the month of Elul is a time of repentance in preparation for the High Holy Days of Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur.

The word "Elul" is similar to the root of the verb "search" in Aramaic. The Talmud writes that the Hebrew word "Elul" can be understood to be an acronym for the phrase "Ani L'dodi V'dodi Li" – "I am my beloved's and my beloved is mine" (Song of Solomon 6:3). Elul is seen as a time to search one's heart and draw close to God in preparation for the coming Day of Judgement, Rosh Hashanah, and Day of Atonement, Yom Kippur.

During the month of Elul, there are a number of special rituals leading up to the High Holy Days.

It is customary to blow the shofar every morning (except on Shabbat) from Rosh Chodesh Elul (the first day of the month) until the day before Rosh Hashanah. The blasts are meant to awaken one's spirits and inspire him to begin the soul searching which will prepare him for the High Holy Days. 
As part of this preparation, Elul is the time to begin the sometimes-difficult process of granting and asking for forgiveness.

It is also customary to recite Psalm 27 every day from Rosh Chodesh Elul through Hoshana Rabbah on Sukkot(in Tishrei).

Aside from the blowing of the shofar, the other significant ritual practice during Elul is to recite selichot (special penitential prayers) either every morning before sunrise beginning on the Sunday immediately before Rosh Hashanah, or, if starting Sunday would not afford four days of selichot, then the Sunday one week prior (Ashkenazi tradition) or every morning during the entire month of Elul. 
Ashkenazi Jews begin the recitation of selichot with a special service on Saturday night between solar mid-night (not 12:00) and morning light on the first day of Selichot.

The days of Awe and Judgement, of reflection and repentance, are a time when use their prayers to seek the Holy One, blessed be He, Who hovers nearby awaiting their call.
The Talmud explains that, of course He can always be found and He is always near, but during the 19 days from Rosh Hashanah to Yom Kippur He is especially available, especially close, especially hopeful, that His children  will have the good sense to seek Him out.

In the various Ashkenazic Selichot rites different prayers are cited each day of the Selichot period. 
Nevertheless the format is the same every day.
The Selichot compositions are inserted into windows in a framework of Scriptural verses and applications. 
In most rites the framework begins with Ashrei (Psalm 145 and Half Kaddish)It closes with another series of verses, the threefold recitation of the Viduy confession more verses, supplications, and finally Tachanun  and the full Kaddish

As part of these ties, which start this year at NIGHTFALL 21 Elul 5778 (the 67th anniversary of my Bar Mitzvah), after Shabbat ends, the Jew is further required to make Teshuva and ask for forgiveness from any sin he may have committed against any Family member, Brother, or Friend during the past year in the form of speech, actions, neglect to act. or even unintended action.

Because this cannot be done on the Shabbat; I hereby formally request forgiveness from any, and all, of whom I may have hurt or insulted, whether intentionally or unintentionally; wittingly or unwittingly, consciously or unconsciously, or in whatever manner I may have done so.

For all this I humbly ask forgiveness.

No answer is required on your part; only the humble request on my part

Shabbat Shalom

L’Shana Tova Tikotavu

Yeruchem David ben Mordecai

Errol Feldman

B"H I will return here after Yom Kippur. 
It is my intention not to post again during these days of Repentance.

Comment: What nobility of spirit you show! כתיבה וחתימה טובה