# Request for forgiveness (from @Tomw)

Tags: discussion

Shalom, and blessings to everyone who uses this site properly.

Inspired by this: [SELICHOT Request for Forgiveness](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/selichot-request-for-forgiveness)

I humbly ask forgiveness of anyone I have offended or upset while using this site, and seek reconciliation where possible.

I’ve posted some bad questions, presumptuous questions and presumptuous answers. Also a snarky comment about eighteen months ago (lack of wit on my part).

I am very grateful to everyone who has helped me here, and I am aware that I have not done well here in the past.

This site is an invaluable resource for me, and therefore I seek peace with all Torah teachers and teachers of Judaism.

I will try to behave better in the future, and am open to any criticism or rebuke that users may offer me.

Please accept my apology, for I wish to learn Torah as best I can.

From a Gentile, and one who will remain faithful to Israel no matter what.

✡️

EDIT: I’ve just realised that I have asked a couple of questions on MY that go beyond the bounds of Gentile Torah study, and given an answer that indicates that I have gone beyond the bounds of Gentile Torah study. I had my reasons for these things, which I won’t go into here, but I am nevertheless deeply sorry and grieved about this. I am aware there is a death penalty for these things, which I accept.  If anyone wishes to intercede, please do. I’m signing off from MY for the time being. Best wishes to all. TW

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because see flag

Comment: @kouty - please forgive my ignorance; may I ask how this post is any different in form to the one I linked to, which received 6 upvotes? Serious question: Do users not have the right to seek peace with fellow-users on this site? If they do, is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: It's the same problem I think, but it's only my opinion.

Comment: @kouty - by the same problem, do you mean presumption? So it’s not apologising here that is the problem, but the lack of humility in the apology?

Comment: @kouty - show me the errors of my ways and I will do teshuvah!

Comment: Don't do teshuva, be happy and learn Torah. After 20 years do teshuva

Comment: @kouty - i don’t understand that, but thanks for the good-will. Any tips you or the other users can give will be warmly appreciated. I’ll leave this alone now.